# IEEE 802.11 RTS/CTS Collision

Tags: wifi, collision, cts

folks! I have the following question: in 802.11 protocol with rts/cts a collision occurs when two host try to send something to other hosts at same time (also an RTS)? in other words I did not understand when a collision occurs using this mechanism...

Answer (score 2):

A small analogy for RTS/CTS: Consider a class with several students. If all students ask question at the same time, professor won't be able to hear anything but a noise (analogy to collision). But if a student wants to ask a question, he raises the hand (analogy to RTS) and professor says, proceed with the question (analogy to CTS).

A station(STA1) which wants send a data to STA2. It first would reserve the medium. STA 1 sends an RTS frame with a duration field in it. Duration indicates for how much time STA wants to reserve the medium

STA2 sends a CTS frame and other stations update their NAV (Network Allocation Vector), so that no other station will transmit any packet for the duration reserved by STA1.